# Problem With Extradata Clique: Genesis File

Tags: private-blockchain, genesis

Can you help me?, so I'm having problems with the Extradata section, so when I fill in the extradata, and when I run it successfully there is no problem, but when I run explorer the address is 0x00000000000000, can you help me? Thank you

File Genesis.json

```
{
"config": {
    "chainId": 1201,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "clique": {
        "period": 5,
        "epoch": 30000
    }
},
"alloc": {
    "0x00000000000000000000000000": { "balance": "1000000000" },
    "0x00000000000000000000000000": { "balance": "1000000000" },
    "0x00000000000000000000000000": { "balance": "1000000000" }
},
"coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"difficulty": "1",
"extraData": "",
"gasLimit": "0x2fefd8",
"mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"nonce": "0",
"timestamp": "0x00"
```

}

Comment: What explorer are you using? If you retrieve the genesis block from the geth's console it contains the expected extraData?